# Catch cmd output while building nsis installer

Tags: nsis

How can I get output from cmd application while compiling NSIS installer?

CMD app returning the string.

I'm trying this but get 0 in the messagebox.

```
!system ".\cmdapp.exe" MYOUTPUT
MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION "${MYOUTPUT}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 there is the exit code. You need to manually redirect the output somewhere.

```
Section
!tempfile stdoutfile
!system 'dir "$%windir%\e*.exe" > "${stdoutfile}"'
!define /file stdout "${stdoutfile}"
!delfile "${stdoutfile}"
MessageBox mb_ok "${stdout}"
SectionEnd
```